# While inside image.onload function, access class object and image object

Tags: typescript

From the code below:

```
class MyClass{
  imageWidth: number = 0;
  img = new Image();
  run(){
    this.img.onload = function(){
      imageWidth = this.naturalWidth; // <--- Want to access imageWidth
    }
  }
}
```

While inside `image.onload`, How can I access `imageWidth` member in the class.
And force eslint to know that `this` is `Image` object

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers the the object you are oberating in. You can access imageWidth by doing `this.imageWidth`. `this.naturalWidth` aren't defined.

You could do `this.img.naturalWidth` if the property comes from the Image. But what you have tried is not how javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

in short words: you need to hint the interpreter what is `this` in given function, eg.:

```
function(this: Image) {
  console.log(this.naturalWidth);
}
```

reference:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters-in-callbacks
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6739